# Send websocket to client every x seconds

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket

How do you send a websocket stream every X seconds?

**Setup where data can be seen from the additionalSocket in the Node console:**

```
io.on('connection', (client) => {
  client.on('subscribe', (interval) => {

    additionalSocket.on('message', (data) => {
      console.log('data', data)
    }) 

    setInterval(() => {
      client.emit('timer', new Date())
    }, interval)
  })
});
```

**Setup where setInterval is in the additionalSocket event but 'ignores' the interval**

```
io.on('connection', (client) => {
  client.on('subscribe', (interval) => {

    additionalSocket.on('message', (data) => {
      console.log('data', data)
      setInterval(() => {
        client.emit('data', data)
      }, interval)
    })       
  })
});
```

**Setup where let is undefined and sends undefined to the client**

I know there is a context issue here because of the closure callback in additionalSocket.on not having access to the outer scope.

```
io.on('connection', (client) => {
  client.on('subscribe', (interval) => {

    let stream 
    additionalSocket.on('message', (data) => {
      stream = data
    })  

    setInterval(() => {
      client.emit('stream', stream)
    }, interval)     
  })
});
```

This server is in node, and the client is in React.
**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using setTimeout, outerVar's value can be seen in the call to setInterval. Now I can pass the `websockets` stream data initiated server side to the client every x seconds.

```
  let outerVar
  setTimeout(() => {
    websocket.on('message', (data) => {
      outerVar = data;
    })
  }, 0)

  setInterval(() => {
    console.log('outerVar', outerVar);
    client.emit('timer', outerVar)
  }, 3000)
```